# How to store the token retrieved from another system in Spring application?

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-security

I'm retrieving token from another system using credentials provided by customer. After the token is retrieved I'm creating a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` and put it into SecurityContextHolder.

**I would like to store the token as well because I'll need it to perform the API calls. Where do I put the token?** I don't like the idea of putting the token to the `password` property of the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`.

You can find the code below:

```
override fun authenticate(authentication: Authentication?): Authentication {
    authentication?.let {
        val email = authentication.name
        val password = authentication.credentials.toString()

        val token = authenticationSource.getAuth(email, password) //  I want to store it somewhere!
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password, listOf(SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER")))
    }

    throw AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication object is equal null")
}
```

Comment: What sort of token? In case of JWT you could instead use `JwtAuthenticationToken` class

Comment: @AivarasPrudnikovas, we just receive the token as a String from the external system, it's not a JWT. The external system returns us something like that: `#Tue Nov 30 13:08:11 PST 2010 AUTHTOKEN=a8b6de25b5bf481824c9c4173c56231a RESULT=TRUE`

Comment: When you are calling the API, how the token will be validated? If it is jwt token then you will need to set it in header as bearer token. Please provide information on how the token validation will happen at API side.

Comment: Are there any constraints on where you have to store it, I mean could you store in any of these: database, session, security context? BTW is your current security context using some other auth details already, or is this token the actual user authentication?

Comment: @AivarasPrudnikovas we don't have a database, application is build on top of API and just extends it with some extra functionality. Security context doesn't store any user details. Do you think it makes sense to implement UserDetails interface and put token into the implementation??? That sounds pretty good for me. Except that there will be some overhead with all the methods which need to be implemented

Comment: I would instead pass the token back to the client as it needs to reuse it later as far as I understand. Client could then make requests with that token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this problem I've provided my own `Principal` implementation:

```
data class UserInfo(val email: String, val token: String) : Principal {
    override fun getName(): String = email
}
```

and then passed the instance of `UserInfo` to the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` constructor :

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(UserInfo(email, token), password, listOf(SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER")))
```

And if you need this token you will be able to retrieve it from the `SecurityContext` the with a simple line of code:

```
(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication.principal as UserInfo).token
```